# I am trying to calculate percentage, and my results are not correct.

Tags: calculus, percentile

Suppose a Student Scores 18.70 out of 30 in Subject1 & 29.75 out of 40 in Subject2.
I have calculated percentage of Subject1 as 62.33% & for Subject2 74.38%.
While calculating the final percentage If I average both percentages I get 68.35% but If I calculating the percentage by adding scores of both Subjects i.e. 48.45 out of 70 the percentage is 69.21%.
I know know 69.21% is correct but I fail to understand why average is coming wrong, and is there any way with which I can get final percentage from percentages in each subject.

I know I am very bad in math,
be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results differ because subject 2 was "more important" than subject 1. (subject 2 represents 40/70 of the whole evaluation and subject 1 represents 30/70). However you can get the final porcentage in this way. $$ \frac{(62.33)(30)+(74.38)(40)}{70}=69.21$$

This is called weighted average.

Comment: How do you know the weight to assign to each subject's percentage?

Comment: "subject 2 represents 40/70 of the whole evaluation and subject 1 represents 30/70" So weights are 40 and 30 respectively. Then it is divided by the sum of the weights.

Comment: @User58220 Hello, I have just seen your answer, my reputation is less than 50 so I can not respod there. I agree with you, the question is not that clear but citing from the question "if I calculating the percentage by adding scores of both Subjects i.e. 48.45 out of 70". So with this I assume the weights are 30 and 40.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the original post just what is being asked,

There are two subjects.  The assessment tool to evaluate each one has a different maximum number of possible marks.  This decision does not have anything to do with the relative importance of the two subjects.

You have correctly converted these marks to percentages, so the results in the two subjects can be compared.

**If you were told that the two subjects were equally important** in finding the overall mark, you would average the two percentages.

**If you were told that the subjects' importance was in direct proportion to the total marks available in each one,** then you would proceed as in the accepted answer.  But what if the instructor in Subject #1 decides to report the mark as $187$ out of $300$?  Does that change the students overall program grade? Should it?

Answer (score 0):

try this if it makes sense;
18.7 + 29.75=48.45 this is your total score out of 70 right,
now lets assume you have the first test 5/5 and the second 43.45/65 which is 48.45/70....the same value right? 
but if you do the percentage now its (100%+66.8%)/2=83.4%

you are giving a different weight from from different measurments the same weight and consequently influencing the final value. I would simply add numerators and denominator and then calculate the final percentage or do what Jose Luis said above to account for the differnt weights of measurments.

Comment: But suppose the Assessment Section of the Course Outline said that the two subjects were of equal importance in determining the final mark?

Comment: weight won't be an issue then :)